# Bitbucket/git cant see changed files in status after git reset

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-bash

I am using bitbucket with GIT. i made a mistake by committing and pushing some code to the master branch , i thought i was doing to dev branch. To revert I did **"git reset --hard HEAD~1"** then did **"git push --force"** , this removed the commit and made reverted the master to previous commit all good i think. Now i want to push my local changes to dev branch , So i did **"git checkout dev"** then hit **"git status"**,I got

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Dev'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I still see all the changes in my local then why is git saying no changes ? how can i push the changes in my local to the dev branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you committed your changes to master initially and did `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, that commit is gone for good. Now, there are no changes in your local. If you still want to get that commit id and apply it to dev branch, do `git reflog`, find the commit id, checkout dev branch and cherry pick it.